# Dropbox API Cursors: how long are they valid for and using them properly over time

Tags: java, dropbox-api

I've been testing the list files API (still using a development account, maybe that's part of the problem?), but seeing unexpected results. Basically, I ask info on a path, process the results, and then ask for a "new" cursor via "listFolderGetLatestCursor" but it says there are no changes.  Am I missing something?

**Question:** How long is a cursor valid for?

**Problem:** If I run the following method with a `null` cursor in path `/tmp` and set aside the cursor as `cursor1` and then modify files in `/tmp` and then run the same method with `cursor1` after 1 day, getting back `cursor2` it doesn't show any changes.  Sometimes, I seem to get expected results when I run it in shorter time-intervals, but I must be missing something.

```
public String doDropboxWork(String path, String cursor) {
  // make request for path
    if (cursor == null) {
        ListFolderBuilder listFolderBuilder = client.files().listFolderBuilder(path);
        result = listFolderBuilder.withRecursive(true).withIncludeDeleted(false).start();
    } else {
        result = client.files().listFolderContinue(cursor);
    }

    while (true) {
       // ... do work ....
        if (!result.getHasMore()) {
            break;
        }
        result = client.files().listFolderContinue(result.getCursor());
    }

   // get new cursor
   String cursor2 = client.files().listFolderGetLatestCursor(path).getCursor();
   return cursor2;
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/208435823-how-long-is-a-cursor-valid-for- ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on feedback from the Dropbox Forum, the fix is to not ask for a new cursor:

```
eg:
//String cursor2 = client.files().listFolderGetLatestCursor(path).getCursor();
```

as this resets the polling

Comment: Official doc source that states that ?

Comment: If you've found an official documentation source for that I'm happy to update the ticket with it, but no, I couldn't find any... just the helpful response I got on the user forum.